# Error on sendSignTransaction: invalid argument 0: json: cannot unmarshal non-string into Go value of type hexutil.Bytes

Tags: web3js

I'm encountering the above error when trying to send a transaction. Answers to similar questions seem to indicate to prepend `0x` on all addresses/key but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

```
const Web3 = require('web3')

const w3 = new Web3('https://rpc-mumbai.maticvigil.com/v1/<api_key>')

 const key = '0x3c9c....'
 const address = '0x3c6E2d83dFAd3858B55C978576b0Ba697C50a43c'

const rawTx = {
    nonce: 0,
    from: address,
    to: '0xe381c25de995d62b453af8b931aac84fccaa7a62',
    gas: 62700,
    value: '0x0',
    chainId: 80001
};

const signedTx = w3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(rawTx, key)

const receipt = w3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx).then(res => {
  console.log(res)
}).catch(e =>
  console.log('error: ', e))
```

also tried hex values for nonce, gas, removing chainId:

```
const rawTx = {
...
nonce: '0x0',
gas: '0x3632373030',
...
}
```

This is my first dive into this ecosystem and am simply trying to get any transaction to work.

Comment: you can't send transactions to mumbai without `chainId` , they enforce EIP155

Comment: looks like it is complaining about 0, the parameter you are using 0 is the nonce, maybe nonce has to be hex-encoded too